Companies doing mind control to make you buy things
All I can remember is a man is running through a city where he is seeing colorful CGI looking blobs/objects in the sky. but i think only he can see them. I thought I remember it being about companies doing mind control to make you buy things. They find out he can see these things and chase after him. Any ideas?
I should have added it is not They Live. I think it's more recent like past 3 years. I also thought it had something to do with the word "Logo" something in the title. I could have completely dreamed this as the more I think about it.
The blobs/objects of different shapes were seemed to come out of buildings. the blobs also start attacking him. (for some reason I start to think of bees similar to the bees from "Lawnmower Man")

Any more details you remember that might help identification? When did you see it? From what time period was it? From what country was it?

"Should of added it is not They Live" - Too late, though. ;)

Found it! It's called Branded YouTube trailer they won't let me post the answer though yet

"Companies doing mind control to make you buy things" Isn't that called advertising?

I remember seeing that preview, and fortunately recalled the movie to be Branded. The trailer exactly matches your description. It was released in September 2012, so you're correct about the approximate time of its release.

It sounds a little like They Live (1988), in which special glasses enabled the user to see the occupying aliens' subliminal messages (and the aliens themselves).  However, the messages were all in black and white, and I don't think they were CGI:


Yeah great movie but not it :(

It somehow reminds me of the John Carpenter classic They Live. Yet it is actually rather the opposite, since the protagoinst doesn't see colorful things, but everything is black and white when he wears special sunglasses he found. Using these he sees that some people are actually aliens and that the whole world is full of big messages like "OBEY" or "CONSUME". Once they realize "he can see", they start to chase him and he meets some fellows forming a kind of resistance. The whole movie is actually a bit of a satire (yet not a very subtle or elaborate one, though) on the consume and money oriented "yuppyism" of the 80s.

Perhaps this is the first question, where same answer has been posted as two different answers by two different  users! :P
